# PDF invoices totals - switch shipping and tax

Tags: invoice, totals

My totals are displayed wrong on PDF invoices meaning, my taxes are listed below my shipping. On the cart and in the sales emails is all ok, like: 
Price 
Tax 
Shipping

and only on my PDF invoices it is like

Price 
Shipping 
Tax

Where are the informations for PDF invoice totals defined?

Answer (score 2):

The sort order of the totals in the pdf is determined by, funnily enough, their sort_order attribute in /app/code/core/Mage/Sales/etc/config.xml

```
<config>
  <global>
        <!-- SNIP -->
        <pdf>
            <!-- SNIP -->
            <totals>
                <subtotal translate="title">
                    <title>Subtotal</title>
                    <source_field>subtotal</source_field>
                    <font_size>7</font_size>
                    <display_zero>1</display_zero>
                    <sort_order>100</sort_order>
                </subtotal>
                <discount translate="title">
                    <title>Discount</title>
                    <source_field>discount_amount</source_field>
                    <amount_prefix>-</amount_prefix>
                    <font_size>7</font_size>
                    <display_zero>0</display_zero>
                    <sort_order>200</sort_order>
                </discount>
                <shipping translate="title">
                    <title>Shipping &amp; Handling</title>
                    <source_field>shipping_amount</source_field>
                    <font_size>7</font_size>
                    <display_zero>0</display_zero>
                    <sort_order>400</sort_order>
                </shipping>
                <adjustment_positive translate="title">
                    <title>Adjustment Refund</title>
                    <source_field>adjustment_positive</source_field>
                    <font_size>7</font_size>
                    <display_zero>0</display_zero>
                    <sort_order>500</sort_order>
                </adjustment_positive>
                <adjustment_negative translate="title">
                    <title>Adjustment Fee</title>
                    <source_field>adjustment_negative</source_field>
                    <font_size>7</font_size>
                    <display_zero>0</display_zero>
                    <sort_order>600</sort_order>
                </adjustment_negative>
                <grand_total translate="title">
                    <title>Grand Total</title>
                    <source_field>grand_total</source_field>
                    <font_size>8</font_size>
                    <display_zero>1</display_zero>
                    <sort_order>700</sort_order>
                </grand_total>
            </totals>
        </pdf>
  <global>
</config>
```

In a default Magento install there is no back-end setting (like there is for the checkout totals) to change this.

You can copy the above into your own module's config.xml file and then adjust the sort_order to your liking (cache refresh needed after any edits).

Answer (score 1):

Late to the game here, but for others having this issue, you just create a module for your site and add the following to that modules `etc/config.xml` file (within `<global>...</global>`):

```
<pdf>
   <totals>
      <tax translate="title">
         <sort_order>410</sort_order>
      </tax>
   </totals>
</pdf>
```

Note that this is not found in the core/Sales module as the other answer states, it is found here: `/app/code/core/Mage/Tax/etc/config.xml`